# E/R diagram: better multiple entities or single entity with many rows with null values?

Tags: entity-relationship

I'm designing an e/r diagram for a web application and I'm having a doubt on which alternative is better between the 2 following:

- 3 different entities connected to 3 other entities that are basically the same, with 1 to N relations;
- 3 different entities connectes to 1 other entity,  with 1 to N relation for each connection;

My thought is that in first option I'll have 3 tables with completely full rows, while in second option I'll have only one table but with at least 2 null attributes per row (2 of the 3 foreign keys).

I made an explicative drawing here:
[example of e/r diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB00V.png)